# PHP exec() command problem

Tags: php, command, exec

On my php page

I have this exec function converting pdf to swf

> exec('"C:\\Program
>   Files\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe"
>   "C:\\Program
>   Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\system\\logs\\reports\\temp\\sample.pdf"
>   -o "C:\\Program Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\system\\logs\\reports\\temp\\sample.swf"
>   -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters');

on my **localhost** it works but whenever I put that function on another server let's say http://192.168.0.2:8888/system/ it doesn't convert the pdf at all...

Please help me get through this...

thanks

Comment: did you have the same directory and full path on your server?

Comment: Where's the error message? Doesn't `exec` return error? Why didn't you looked at php error logs? -1 for bad explanation.

Comment: on the server, the script is this

exec('"C:\\Program Files\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\system\\logs\\reports\\temp\\sample.pdf" -o "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\system\\logs\\reports\\temp\\sample.swf" -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters');

Comment: there are no error logs generating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I already resolved my problem here. for others to know what I've done;

here's my code

```
// First, I create a new .bat file using fopen

$ourFileName = "C:\\FILE\\PATH\\TO\\sample.bat";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");

// Then write the content in it with your pdf2swf.exe syntax to convert from PDF to SWF

fwrite($ourFileHandle, '"C:\\Program Files\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe" "C:\\FILE\\PATH\\TO\\sample.pdf" -o "C:\\FILE\\PATH\\TO\\sample.swf" -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters');

// Close the handle
fclose($ourFileHandle);

// After all above executed successfully, we now run the newly created .bat file using PHP exec() function.

exec('"C:\\FILE\\PATH\\TO\\sample.bat"');
```

I don't know if there are any other way to do this but this works for me

using Windows Server 2003 with Apache 2 and PHP 5.2

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side. `exec()` only works with commands on your server. When using `exec()`, imagine being physically on your server and typing these commands. I assume your problem is that you don't have the program `C:\\Program Files\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe` on your server and that the files aren't there either.

Comment: please take a look at this image

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/202/execproblem.jpg/

I already execute the command via cmd prompt and it's a success... it converts the pdf to swf on my server...